# bash - replace all occurrences in a line with a captured pattern from that line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have an input file:

```
a=,1,2,3
b=,4,5,6,7
c=,8,9
d=,10,11,12
e=,13,14,15
```

That I need to transform into

```
 a/1 a/2 a/3
 b/4 b/5 b/6 b/7
 c/8 c/9
 d/10 d/11 d/12
 e/13 e/14 e/15
```

So I need to capture the phrase before the `=` sign and replace every comma with  `\1/`.

My most successful attempt was:

```
sed 's@\([^,]*\)=\([^,]*\),@\2 \1/@g'
```

but that would only replace the first occurrence.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `sed` isn't very good for this because the `/g` will cause searching to resume *after* the previous match instead of reprocessing the entire line. You can work around this with a loop, but I would go with Awk for this.

Comment: is the first space in expected output optional or required?

Comment: space is optional

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With **`awk`**:

```
awk -F'[=,]' '{ for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s/%s%s", $1,$i,(i==NF? ORS:OFS) }' file
```

The output:

```
a/1 a/2 a/3
b/4 b/5 b/6 b/7
c/8 c/9
d/10 d/11 d/12
e/13 e/14 e/15
```

---

Or a shorter one with `gsub/sub` substitution:

```
awk -F'=' '{ gsub(",", OFS $1"/"); sub(/^[^ ]+ /, "") }1' file
```

Comment: Nice. Could you please explain this part `(i==NF? ORS:OFS)` ?

Comment: @Mago, if we reach the last field `i==NF?` -> print `ORS` (newline) , otherwise -> print `OFS` (space) for other fields. Thus, adding record separator on encountering last field

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, my solution is little closer to you, a disclaimer: no copy has been done, it is little different I believe :)

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk -F"=" '{gsub(/\,/,FS $1"/");$1="";gsub(/^ +| +$/,"")} 1'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation too now for above solution:

```
awk -F"=" '{
gsub(/\,/,FS $1"/");  ##Using global substitution and replacing comma with FS(field separator) $1 and a / for all occurrences of comma(,).
$1="";                ##Nullifying the first column now.
gsub(/^ +| +$/,"")    ##Globally substituting initial space and space at last with NULL here.
}
1                     ##awk works on method of condition then action, so by mentioning 1 making condition TRUE here and not mentioning any action so by default action is print of the current line.
' Input_file          ##Mentioning the Input_file name here.
```

Output will be as follows:

```
a/1 a/2 a/3
b/4 b/5 b/6 b/7
c/8 c/9
d/10 d/11 d/12
e/13 e/14 e/15
```

Answer (score 1):

With sed

```
sed -E '
:A
s/([^=]*)(=[^,]*),([^,]*)/\1\2\1\/\3 /
tA
s/.*=//
' infile
```